# Input line is too long - Spark

Tags: apache-spark, h2o, sparkling-water

I am getting following error while executing `sparkling-shell2.cmd` bat file. I walked through and I am getting this error while executing `spark-shell.cmd` with following paramters

```
cd %TOPDIR%
%SPARK_HOME%/bin/spark-shell.cmd --jars %TOPDIR%/assembly/build/libs/%FAT_JAR% --driver-memory %DRIVER_MEMORY% --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-XX:MaxPermSize=384m" %*
```

> Error: The input line is too long.

How do I solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Windows the maximum length of command line is 260 characters and you are hitting the limit.

Your options are to change multiple of %DEF% operators into one single operator and reduce the overall length with some experimentation.